# Keras CNN issue

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to write a Siamese Network, using Negative Sampling, Code with just 20 examples (positive & Negative included)
Each example include 2 images (x1,x2) and an output indicating if the images are same or not

```
image1           image1        1
image1           image2        0
```

For this i am interested in getting just the last layer, which is Dense() layer in Keras, both X1 and X2 seperately.

The shape of X1 is 20,28,28,1 and X2 is 20,28,28,1
Both have type as numpy.ndarray

But when i apply CNN model, it gives the following error.

**"TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: (28, 28, 1)**

See the python code below

```
model = Sequential([(Image1[0].shape),
            Conv2D(16,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=[1,1],padding='same',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(),name='conv1'),
            Activation('relu'),
            MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
            Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=[2,2],padding='same',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(),name='conv2'),
            Activation('relu'),
            Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=[2,2],padding='same',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(),name='conv3'),
            Activation('relu'),
            MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
            Flatten(),
            Dense(20)
          ])
```

Can someone help me on how to fix this error ?

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: Update keras to 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

The first model layer should specify the shape of the images that you are going to feed. In your case you are adding the image shape as a layer.

Take a look on how to do it:

```
IM_WIDTH = 128
IM_HEIGHT = 128

model = Sequential(
Conv2D(16, input_size=(IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH, 3), kernel_size=(3,3),strides=[1,1],padding='same',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(),name='conv1'),
            Activation('relu'),
            MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
            Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=[2,2],padding='same',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(),name='conv2'),
            Activation('relu'),
            Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=[2,2],padding='same',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(),name='conv3'),
            Activation('relu'),
            MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
            Flatten(),
            Dense(20)
          ])
```